# How to send an array from child component to parent component in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am creating a react application where I have to send an array from child component to parent component. I am trying to send using callback function now but its not working.

Here's my child component:

```
var apis=[]
export default class ApiDropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      options: [],
      suboptions: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchOptions();
  }

  fetchOptions() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/groups")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ options: json });
      });
  }
  //SETTING THE apis here,just adding few elements,its a long function
  onSubmit()
  {
    this.props.apisgranted(apis)
  }


  render() {
  
    return (
      
       
        <div>
          <button type="button" className="btn" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> //Save button to set data in the prop.
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

Now here's my parent component:

```
const AddTask = ({ onAdd, onStatusChange }) => {
  const [client_name, setText] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const [showMessage,setMessage]=useState(false)
  const [apigrants,setapigrants]=useState([])

  
 const handleApiGrants = (langValue) => {
    
    setapigrants(langValue) //setting the props array here from child component
    console.log(apigrants)  //nothing gets printed here
}


 

 
  
  return (
    <form className="add-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div>
   
      <button onClick={setmessage.bind(false, true)} type="button" className="btn">Grant API's</button>
      
      { showMessage && (<ApiDropDown apisgranted={handleApiGrants} />) } //calling the props handling function where which should set the apigrants array with props array.
      
      </div>
```

In my child component,I am using `onSubmit` function to set the array to prop.
In my parent component,First i am declaring `apigrants` array as empty and later assigning it to prop array from child component using `handleApiGrants` function.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Put some value like `this.props.apisgranted('test data')` and you will see this at parent component. You are sending empty array from child component.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be to define the variable in the parent component and also pass it down to the child, like you do with handleApiGrants